# Unable to mount kerberized nfs?

Tags: centos, kerberos, nfs4

I want to configure kerberized nfs, and export /data/books 
I have 3 servers: ipa, server, client
I configured ipa and added nfs service.
My Steps are:

- In ipa:

  ```
  ipa service-show nfs/server.linux.rhce.com
  ipa-getkeytab -s ipa.linux.rhce.com -p nfs/server.linux.rhce.com  -k /etc/krb5.keytab
  ```
- In server:

  ```
  scp ipa:/etc/krb5.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
  semanage fcontext -a -t krb5_keytab_t /etc/krb5.keytab
  restorecon -R /etc/krb5.keytab 
  systemctl start nfs-server
  firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=nfs
  firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=mountd
  firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=rpc-bind
  firewall-cmd --reload
  ```

  And in /etc/exports

  ```
  /data/books   *(sec=krb5p,rw,no_root_squash)
  ```
- In cleint:

  ```
  scp ipa:/etc/krb5.keytab /etc/krb5.keytab
  semanage fcontext -a -t krb5_keytab_t /etc/krb5.keytab
  restorecon -R /etc/krb5.keytab
  ```

  When I tried to mount the /book/data on the client

  ```
  mount -o sec=krb5 server:/data/books /mnt
  ```

  I got this message:

  ```
  mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
  ```

Any help!

Comment: `nfs4` does not require any other service to be exposed to the network. You can remove the holes you've added for `mountd` and `rpc-bind`.

Comment: the reason for that I want to use showmount in nfs-client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `/etc/exports` you specified `sec=krb5p`, so that all traffic will be authenticated and encrypted.

But in your mount command, you specified `sec=krb5`, but this does not match. This must be the same as the option given in `/etc/exports`.